# Get string by const reference

Tags: c++, c++11

```
std::string f(){
   return "xx";
}

int main(){

const std::string& ref = f();
// use ref
}
```

`f` returns temporary string by value. `main` "catch" it by const reference. 
Is it ok in C++?

Comment: It's fine, the temporary lives as long as the reference does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fine. [Temporary](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary) could be bound to lvalue-reference to const or rvalue reference, and its lifetime will be extended to the lifetime of the reference.

> Whenever a reference is bound to a temporary or to a subobject thereof, the lifetime of the temporary is extended to match the lifetime of the reference

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's fine: the lifetime of the `std::string` is extended to the lifetime of the `const` reference.

But note that the behaviour is not *transitive*: i.e. don't assign a `const` reference to `ref`, expecting that to extend the lifetime even further.

Comment: That's a new idea to me, some code illustrating it would be helpful

Comment: `string const& PassThru(string const& s) { return s; }` called with `string const& oops = PassThru("kaboom");`, the temporary with "kaboom" will not be lifetime extended.